# Conditional in NextJS Middleware.ts with NextAuth

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I'm looking to use a conditional in the NextJS `middleware.ts` and I'm using an env variable to decide which parts of the matcher field will be. Either `["/folder/(.*)"]` or `["/no-match"]`.

From what I understand, this is valid JavaScript since I get the expected result testing in an isolated page.

```js
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware"

export const config = {
  matcher:
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_USERS === "true"
      ? ["/folder/(.*)"]
      : ["/no-match"],
}
```

NOTE: `"true"` because boolean env args are strings.

I get an error:

```
Unsupported node type "ConditionalExpression" at "config.matcher".
The default config will be used instead.
Read More - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-page-config
```

It says conditionals not allowed so is there another way I can use this logic?

Change to one of the options works fine.